# «…оглянулся направо, на ржаное поле, на котором(,) у телеги(,) сидели мужики»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

> Кучер остановил четверню и оглянулся направо, на ржаное поле, на котором **у телеги** сидели мужики.

Мне не совсем понятно, почему «у телеги» здесь не считается уточнением и не обособляется. Ведь есть же переход от более широкого понятия («на котором», то есть на поле) к более узкому («у телеги»).

Comment: А я не понимаю, как можно "оглянуться направо" - вряд ли кучер сидел боком, лицом в левую сторону. Вы хотите обособить "у телеги" отделением его запятой от слова "котором" - каким образом его можно "уточнить"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любопытными показались мне **и вопрос, и комментарий**.К вопросу, правда, больших претензий нет – это цитата из романа Толстого «Анна Каренина».  «Кучер остановил четверню и оглянулся направо, на ржаное поле, на котором у телеги сидели мужики». https://ilibrary.ru/text/1099/p.174/index.html

**1. Ответ на вопрос**

Почему не обособляется  обстоятельство «у телеги», которое по смыслу явно уточняющее (оно сужает значение обстоятельства «ржаное поле»)? Всё дело в том, что обособление обстоятельства зависит **не только от смысла, но и от структуры предложения.** В данном случае обстоятельство неудобно обособлять ни графически (слишком много получится запятых), ни интонационно (внутри нераспространенного придаточного предложения). Также во многих случаях это авторское решение, которое позволяет при обособлении выделить и подчеркнуть нужное слово.

2. **Замечания по поводу комментария**: А я не понимаю, как можно "оглянуться направо" — вряд ли кучер сидел боком, лицом в левую сторону. Вы хотите обособить "у телеги" отделением его запятой от слова "котором" — каким образом его можно "уточнить"?

2.1. Вероятно, Толстой имел в виду «посмотрел направо». Из словаря: ОГЛЯНУТЬСЯ,  1. Обернувшись, повернув голову, посмотреть назад, **в сторону**.

2.2. **А можно ли уточнить союзное слово** «на котором», замещающее обстоятельство?  Оказывается, без проблем, если это позволяет структура предложения, например:

Подойдя к столу, **на котором, среди разбросанных в беспорядке бумаг,** лежала четвертушка повестки,  он выдвинул верхний ящик и вынул что-то.  [Елена Чижова, 2002]

А можно и не обособлять, это авторское решение: Юра вошел в комнату, увидел зажженную елку, накрытый стол, **на котором среди тарелок с разноцветной едой** таинственно поблескивали два высоких бокала… [Анна Берсенева (2005)]